# Google cast - android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton style

Tags: google-cast

how can I change icons of android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton ? I want to use my custom colour icons. I tried to set  externalRouteEnabledDrawable but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Icons should have the same name as the ones in the support lib and you need icons in different sizes to put in 4 folders: 
drawable-hdpi , drawable-mdpi , drawable-xhdpi , drawable-xxhdpi

Names in the v22 start with ic... (Example: ic_cast_on_light)
in previous versions it started with mr...

I have done it and it works.